# Can I install windows & ubuntu on an intel xeon 1230 which doesn't have onboard graphics?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, graphics-card, cpu

I'm building a PC. I've bought an nvidia graphics card and need a CPU. I was thinking of an Intel Xeon 1230. This chip doesn't have on-board graphics. But will I be able to install Ubuntu & Windows using the CPU for graphics so I can get far enough to then install the nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have your graphics card installed. :)

The graphics adapter will be run in a standard mode (VGA usually) using a generic driver, until you can provide a more specific driver.